# SVG render SDK vs NDK

Tags: android, performance, svg, android-ndk, performance-testing

I would like to know what is the speed difference at rendering SDK side and NDK side with bigger SVG files.

I have tried with NDK [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213655/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-out-of-stack-in-jni-pushlocalframe) but doesn't support bigger SVG files.
Probably the best SDK parser -at least this is I am using is [androidsvg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)

Does it worth the effort to get into Native side? - no heap limit, if the recursive calls are rewritten to iterative ones.

SDK depends on device: 1-12 sec rendering with a big SVG file ( 350kb ).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how is with NDK, but I took 2x phone with same Android OS and same svg.

Nexus One with 4.2.2 ( Cyanogen mode )

[image: n1]

Thl w8s , aka Galaxy s4 Chinese clone:

[image: w8s]

I starting I have printed out the max available memory, with large heap enabled.

Than loaded the svg file from assets. An svg made by artists, has around 350kb the file, and the SVG dom object has aroung 7-8Mb in memory, so this is not a circle + 1 rectangle....

Than based on screen resolution need to render the svg to a square area.

The 480x800 to a 356x356 area.

The 1080x1920 phone to a bigger area, you can do the math, now  I am lazy. Anyway, this need to fill a lot more pixel area.

I think the 400 milliseconds it is an acceptable result from him to make a logo / background. Not need to re-draw often, since isn't a game element.

For games: at first time loading transform from SVG to png all files and use the cached one.
It will take time, only the first time.
It will take space , user can clear it. - than re-make, if needed